# Generate random letters

Tags: c++, random

```
string bolsa_letras::letters_generator(int quantity){
    int already_generated = 0;
    map<char, int> aux = values;
    string out;
    while(already_generated != quantity){
        char generated_char = 'A' + rand()%26;
        if(aux[generated_char] > 0){
            out.push_back(generated_char);
            aux[generated_char]--;
            already_generated++;
        }
    }

    return out;
}
```

Above is the code that given a number generates random letters.

The map saves the letters and the times that letters can be appeared. The problem is that every time i run the code, it prints the same: NLRBBMQH. Why is so?

I have include cstdlib for the rand function.

Comment: You need to seed the PRNG. Use `srand`.

Comment: Don't use `rand()`. Use [proper random generators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

Comment: @Fureeish thank you for your answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A deterministic program cannot naturally generate randomness. We need to get that randomness from elsewhere. In the old days of [`rand()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand), we'd generally [*seed*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand) the [RNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation) with the result of [`std::time(NULL)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) to produce a different state at each run.

Nowadays, we use the tools provided by [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) which are "more random".

From [cppreference.com's documentation on `std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) you can find an example for integers of type `int`. Now, `char` is an integer type too. Let us tweak their example a tiny bit:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;  // Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); // Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()
    std::uniform_int_distribution<char> dis('A', 'Z');

    for (int n=0; n<10; ++n) {
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

And tadaaaa! a random letter generator :)

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40bd142071e96162)